# Can I install a receptacle outlet below a window?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance

I need to add a receptacle outlet to an existing line.  I will run the line from an existing receptacle outlet.  Is it okay to locate the new outlet below an existing window?

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  As long as you have part of the wall under your window (your window doesn't go to the floor) then it is treated like any other wall in your house.

Comment: Think we need to hear from one of the NEC gurus. MY guys won't install interior receptacles under opening windows now in new construction.

Comment: @shirlockhomes - I have had three houses (one mine, two I am rehabbing) pass inspection the past 4 months.  All have had multiple outlets under windows.  All three cities used NEC 2011.  Would like to hear if something has changed.  Also one of mine wouldn't have passed the 6 foot rule without doing it.  What would you do with rooms with very wide windows - which is becoming a trend in my area.

Comment: I am curious, I really don't know the answer. I've had close-in  inspections fail for outlets under a window.  might be local, I'm not the NEC expert, but we have a couple of guys on here that are well versed.

Comment: I just searched my copy of the NEC and the only indoor considerations for windows is that overhead lighting must be at least 3 feet from window.  My area is very strict with electrical inspections and they commented on some very ridiculous things but never mentioned receptacles under windows.

Comment: If there was electric baseboard heaters under window then it would be a problem

Comment: @shirlockhomes I don't think there is anything in the code that specifically says you can't put a receptacle under a window. However, I think it's common practice to avoid it where possible. The inspector *might* consider the area under a window a damp location, and so would require the outlet to meet those requirements.  Next time you see the inspector, I'd ask him for a code reference. It may well be a local twist.

Comment: @DMoore Even if the window goes floor to ceiling, it still counts as wall space (NEC 2014 210.52(A)(2)(2)). The only exception would be, if it's the sliding portion of a sliding door. If you had a sun room where the walls were covered in floor to ceiling windows, receptacle outlets would still be required in the room.  In this case, however, you'd have to install them in the floor within 18 in. of the wall.

Comment: It must be a local thing here. Tester is the NEC guru! If it was in the code, he would find it.

Comment: If it is true it is definitely a local amendment. If it is then it is the first I have EVER heard this. Nothing like this is in the NEC.
I also don't think it is possible for an inspector to consider this a damp location. Even then it is treated no differently than any other interior room in a home. Think about bathroom receptacles.
Personally I think it is just another case of a rogue inspector making up his own rules.

Comment: I have an electrician coming into a job in a few days. I'm definitely gonna ask him what the scoop is here in my parts.

Comment: I have to say over the past few years I have become way more familiar with the NEC than I have ever wanted to be.  I have had a few crews do electrical work for me and I hear crap like this from time to time.  Who knows maybe an inspector at one point told them, an old boss, whatever... but they have "odd" rules like this and I usually ask them where it is in the NEC or I just quit using them.  I have to say that maybe 10-20% of local electricians consult the NEC as much as Tester does.  I don't want a crew that will charge me an extra 1K and not challenge inspector.

Comment: @DMoore I only quote NEC to validate the information I'm providing.  The truth is (aside from code changes), most Electricians rarely have to consult NEC because they have a good understanding of their trade. As for challenging the inspector. Most folks don't choose to challenge the AHJ, because they don't want their work more closely examined in the future.  If you call out the inspector, you'd better make sure **all** your work is to the exact letter of the code.

Comment: @Tester101 - maybe my wording was too harsh.  By challenge inspector I meant just ask them why he is asking for something or to ask him if something will work - instead of assuming that inspector from XXX county said don't do it, so now I will never do it.  I have a really good relationship with inspectors in the area and want to keep it that way so I understand where you are coming from. The point I was making was more about communication.  For instance if I were shirlock homes I would simply ask next inspector about the receptacle under window and challenge his crew after.

Comment: Hey guys, the inspector from Sebago Lake Maine was at a job I am subing on. I asked him about this question. he said he knew of no code violation for an outlet under a window. Ironically, he did say I was not the first to ask him about it. so it seams I had an electrician on a job that wouldn't do it in that town because he knew the inspector had a thing about it. Over the years I have run into some pretty hard headed inspectors that take glee in being difficult.

Comment: If there is a wall below the window this space is included in the distance between outlets and depending on other outlet locations one may be required under the window (think picture window) dmoore is correct that the NEC is ok with outlets under a window and may even require them.+  note NEC exhibit 210.26 shows a fixed glass panel 2' wide with an outlet (any space greater than 2' requires one)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Under widows does not appear to be a useable wall space for a receptical in The City of Calgary's current homeowners electrical wiring guidelines.  However, my house in Calgary built in 1997 has several recepticals under windows.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized after commenting this is a very old question I referenced NEC 2017 below but this info has not changed in decades tried to edit but two slow.

If there is a wall below the window this space is included in the distance between outlets and depending on other outlet locations one may be required under the window (think picture window) dmoore is correct that the NEC is ok with outlets under a window and may even require them.+

note NEC exhibit 210.26 shows a fixed glass panel 2' wide with an outlet (any space greater than 2' requires an outlet). 210.52.2 specifys the space measured along the floor and around corners unbroken by doorways , and similar openings...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps anyone but my home was built in Calgary in 2001.  Almost all my windows have internal recepticals directly under them in every room in the house for both fixed and opening windows.  Also one of my two external outlets is directly under a fixed window.  The only room where this is different is in the developed  basement where the outlets are below but just on the opposite side of the stud for the window frames.
Cheers